# link_url not responding to config.action_controller.relative_url_root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, mod-proxy

I'm running my Rails app on port 3000, with mod_proxy forwarding requests to /rails, to `http://localhost:3000`.

I'm attempting to make `link_to` take the subdirectory into account. (For example, `/rails/user/login` instead of `/user/login`)

But when accessing through the Apache proxy, this doesn't happen. It does, however, work when accessing `http://mysite.com:3000` directly.

Any ideas? I'm tearing my hair out!